# Payment Gateway Response Page Displays empty values in VPS Hosting

Tags: php, windows, payment-gateway, vps, plesk

I was integrating a Test Payment Gateway Kit of IDBI Bank(PHP KIT), The Test Kit is working fine But response page displays all the values as empty and this happens in Godaddy VPS Hosting for windows but when the same code is put in shared hosting it works fine without any problem and i'm able to receive the response values  and display it to the user , i'm literally confused any help/suggestion would be gratefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found The Solution

I Was Using The Response Domain URL has www.abc.com/response.php

Where in the original URL was abc.com/response.php

when i removed www. i am getting the response.

Answer (score 0):

Think the cause is SSL connection issue.
PHP on windows doesn't use OS CA certificates database as on Linux.

Check this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053/1592008

Comment: Does SSL issue leads the payment gateway server to untrust  certificate/ stop sending the response to the response URL , which leads in empty values?

Comment: It's one of possible reasons. Of course it should be debugged first.