# Scheduling Tasks file to call an MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I want to send a sms for users every day in 21:00.

I add a class with function `Send` that send sms for users.

I want to call this function with  Scheduling Tasks in plesk.

How to set this Function for `Path to an executable file *`
 of plesk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up cron task in Plesk 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700749/setting-up-cron-task-in-plesk-11)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is: How do i set my function for `Path to an executable file *`

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700749/setting-up-cron-task-in-plesk-11 ? Put your function into separate script file, request this file from powershell.

Comment: Excuse! should I add a class in my project with function send, and then add this file to host directory and set it for file path?

Comment: i don't understand which type file add in my `MVC` project for defind function that run in every day.